# Update some documents in COUCHBASE

Tags: json, couchbase, document

My task is to upadate some document on couchbase from a file json.
I have these document on couchbase:

**Document 1**

```
{ "id":"1", "car":"bmw", "colore":"white"}
```

**Document 2**

```
{ "id":"2", "car":"mini", "model":"cooper","colore":"black"}
```

**Document 3**

```
{ "id":"3", "car":"ferrari", "model":"california", "colore":"red"}
```

**Document 4**

```
{ "id":"4", "car":"porsche", "model":"cayenne", "colore":"blue"}
```

I receive in a specific folder a File json containing some json to update these documents with the same id:

```
{ "id":"1", "model":"serie1"}   
{ "id":"2", "displacement":"1600"}    
{ "id":"3", "model":"testarossa"}      
{ "id":"4", "style":"suv"}
```

I must import data from these file json.
I try to use command cbimport:
bin\cbimport json -c [host]:8091 -u username -p password -b Default -d file://data/file.json -f lines -g %_id%

The result of cbimport is:
**Document 1**
{ "id":"1", "model":"serie1"}
**Document 2**
{ "id":"2", "displacement":"1600"}
**Document 3**
{ "id":"3", "model":"testarossa"}
**Document 4**
{ "id":"4", "style":"suv"}

The **RESULT** I want is:

**Document 1**
{ "id":"1", "car":"bmw", "colore":"white","model":"serie1"}

**Document 2**
{ "id":"2", "car":"mini","model":"cooper","colore":"black","displacement": "1600"}

**Document 3**
{ "id":"3", "car":"ferrari", "model":"testarossa", "colore":"red"}

**Document 4**
{ "id":"4", "car":"porsche", "model":"cayenne", "colore":"blue", "style":"suv"}

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant code demonstrating your attempt to resolve this, and explain what isn't working correctly with your code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] (and earn a badge while you are at it) / Also read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that cbimport is on your path, just run something like:

```
cbimport json -c couchbase://127.0.0.1 -u your_username -p your_password -b your_bucket_name -d file:///Users/deniswsrosa/Desktop/files.json -f lines -g %id% -t 4
```

Comment: With cbimport I lost the old information in the document.

Comment: i want both the old and new information in the document.